# multiple attributes in a single view phoenix

Tags: serialization, elixir, phoenix-framework

I want to have a single view but want to render different attributes depending upon the json-api that calls it. For example: the index page does not require all the attributes, so there is no need to call all the attributes for it, while show page needs all the attributes, so it should get all the attributes.

I basically want something like:

```
attributes [:id, :name, :email, :website, :inserted_at, :updated_at]
```

for show and

```
attributes [:id, :name, :email]
```

for index.

I am using ja-serializer for this, so would like a solution in that only.

PS: I can have two different views with corresponding attributes but that seems like a workaround also doesn't make much sense.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your question?—Feel free to have a single view that renders different attributes, no problem.

Comment: I am using Ja-serializer for all the views, so would prefer a solution in that only

Comment: @mudasobwa how can one view have more than one attributes?

Comment: @mudasobwa can you suggest me or give me a link to how to have multiple attributes in single view.

Comment: @mudasobwa please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an optional parameter in render method call. We can specify the fields in "fields" and keep the view as it is.

```
def index(conn, params) do
  render("index.json-api", data: data, opts: [fields: %{"table_name"=> "fields,in,csv,style"}])
end
```

For more, refer to Conditional attribute inclusion in
 https://hexdocs.pm/ja_serializer/JaSerializer.DSL.html

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you post some code. But you can do this within the view. You can define separate `render` function heads for each controller action.

For example:

```
  def render("index.json", %{store: store}) do
    %{data: %{store: %{id: store.sap_id, name: store.name}}}
  end

  def render("show.json", %{store: store}) do
    %{data: %{store: %{id: store.sap_id, name: store.name, other: store.other}}}
  end
```

Above, you have a render function head for each action: `index` and `show`. The function body then builds the correct JSON response. You can use this approach to customise the attributes you want to return.

Comment: So, I am using ja-serializer for rendering attributes. Ja-serializer also helps with serializing associations and has other features as well. When I use your stated method, I won't be able to do all that(Ja-serializer's render method will always be preferred in that case and this render method will be useless). That is why I need something in Ja-serializer only.